# Rank in-order of relation to the current date. [Rails, Sqlite3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

How do I return information in rank of closeness to the current date irrelevant of the year. If Current date is May 26 2011, the date closeness to May 26 is returned first. My problem was this confusion: I have two dates: Date 1: May 24th 2011 and Date 2: June 1st **2010**, ensuring that Date 2 is returned before Date 1. Both because May 24 has passed and also the year factor.

Table:

```
Name Created_at

Bob 2010-06-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)

Mike 2010-05-07

Fife 2011-05-09
```

So it would return if current date is May 26 2011:

```
Bob 2010-06-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)

Mike 2010-05-07

Fife 2011-05-09
```

What I have so far:

```
@awesomeDate = Names.order("name").having("date > ?", Date.today)
```